# Remove the black Box around the Chart in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I want remove the black border of the chart.
I am working on that for 2 days, but still not able to get rid of that.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained on the related github :)
The following statements allow you to hide some parts of the chart, including the one you are talking about.

```
chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
yAxisleft.setDrawGridLines(false);
yAxisleft.setDrawAxisLine(false);
yAxisright.setDrawGridLines(false);
yAxisright.setDrawAxisLine(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

In kotlin

```
 chart.axisRight.apply {
        setDrawGridLines(false)
        setDrawLabels(false)
        setDrawAxisLine(false)
    }
    chart.axisLeft.apply {
        setDrawGridLines(false)
        setDrawLabels(false)
        setDrawAxisLine(false)
    }
    chart.xAxis.apply {
        setDrawGridLines(false)
        setDrawLabels(false)
        setDrawAxisLine(false)
    }
    chart.setDrawGridBackground(false)
    chart.setDrawBorders(false)
```